# flutter: how to make unit test the function in private class?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm learning `flutter unit test` recently. I have a `Login` class extends `StatefulWidget` and naturally a `_LoginState` class. I want to test the `validate` function in the latter class but it's private. How can I do this unit test?